# mongodump refuses to connect with ssl

Tags: mongodb, ssl, tls-1.2, mongodump

I have set up my mongod instance with the following config:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /config/mongo.pem
    CAFile: /config/ca.pem
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true

security:
  authorization: enabled
```

I can connect to it fine with `mongosh`:

```
mongosh --host="<mydomain.com>:27017" --username="root" --db="mydbname" --ssl --authenticationDatabase="admin"
```

But when I try to connect with `mongodump` using the exact same options...:

```
mongodump --host="<mydomain.com>:27017" --username="root" --db="mydbname" --ssl --authenticationDatabase="admin"
```

...It fails with the message `Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers`. Checking the mongod logs I see the following:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-12-08T13:55:30.966+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"<my ip address>","uuid":"41542a35-0815-4fb7-a618-d3ecf6b21a33","connectionId":244,"connectionCount":4}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-12-08T13:55:30.980+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23234,   "ctx":"conn244","msg":"No SSL certificate provided by peer"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-12-08T13:55:30.985+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn244","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"<my ip address>","uuid":"41542a35-0815-4fb7-a618-d3ecf6b21a33","connectionId":244,"connectionCount":3}}
```

These three lines are repeated several times until the connection times out.

I'm wondering why it says `No SSL certificate provided by peer` when I have `allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates` set to `true`. It obviously doesn't seem to be a problem when using mongosh as it connects without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. It was due to an outdated version of `mongodump`.

As I checked the server logs I saw that there was actually one line near the beginning (which I had previously missed) that was different among the repeated ones:

```
"Received wire protocol op code or command that is no longer supported. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal"
```

That's when I went to check the mongodump version using `mongodump --version` and I got the output

```
mongodump version: built-without-version-string
```

It was from an outdated `mongo-tools` package so I uninstalled it with `dpkg -P mongo-tools` (I'm using OS Ubuntu 20.04) and then followed the instructions on [Installing the Database Tools on Linux](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-linux/) to install the newer `mongodb-database-tools`.

Obviously the instructions are gonna different depending on OS/System and which version you want to install, but these were the commands for me:

```
wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu2004-x86_64-100.9.4.deb
sudo apt install ./mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu2004-x86_64-100.9.4.deb
```

After getting the latest version of `mongodump`, it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `CAFile` is pointless in your config, because you don't provide any **client** certificate (and that's the reason why you need `allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true`). Instead it might be required in `mongosh` and/or `mongodump`

```
mongosh --host="<mydomain.com>:27017" --username="root" --db="mydbname" --tlsCAFile=/config/ca.pem --tls --authenticationDatabase="admin"
```

`No SSL certificate provided by peer` is just a warning.

`mongosh` provides option `--tlsUseSystemCA` which does not exist in mongodump. Maybe try [connection string](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/connection-string/):

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://root:password<mydomain.com>:27017?authSource=admin&tls=true&tlsCAFile=/config/ca.pem"

mongosh "mongodb://root:password<mydomain.com>:27017?authSource=admin&tls=true" --tlsUseSystemCA
```

Maybe have a look at [How Security in MongoDB works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317) - which is a bit more advanced.

Comment: I found the solution, posted answer. Due to my mistake of not noticing a line in the log saying the client driver is outdated. Although I wish the server would log the different lines with clear tags in the beginning [ERROR/WARNING/INFO etc.]. Would make it easier.

I didn't realize CAFile was only for client certificate verification. Good to know, then I can remove it. Thanks!